# Arduino: How would you join Arduino code for less text?

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to join certain bits of your arduino code. I need to ad 64 "states". Would it be possible to join the below and if so how?

```
volatile boolean a_state,b_state,c_state,d_state,e_state,f_state,g_state,h_state,i_state = false;
```

Although only 10 "states here I will be adding 64 "states"

Comment: You can do it using the usual flag: `uint8_t state[8]`. You only need 8 bytes, and then access to the bits. But this is C or C++ (I don't know what language you are using, sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for an [array](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/), which can be initialized as follows:

```cpp
volatile bool states[64];
```

Comment: As per usual I have not given enough info. I need to call those staes later ie "    `if (a_state){strip.setPixelColor`     `if (b_state){strip.setPixelColor`    " So  if you se at array how would you add that to your later code?

Comment: You can access the values in the array by indexing into it: if (states[0]) then { ... }. The linked documentation goes over indexing, as well as other helpful array operations.